# Who existed that might have killed Cain?

Tags: adam, genesis-bereishith

In Gen. 1:28 we find G-d instructing them (Adam and Eve) to be fruitful and multiply. Also in Gen 3 we see that her named “the mother of all the living.” Then in Gen. 4 we see G-d telling Cain “Therefore whoever kills Cain...”

Who are these people that Cain is afraid of and G-d warns not to kill Cain?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following the structure of your question, would you be able to update with a couple clarifications?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear to me (and, apparently, to the previous commenter, above). I ___think___ it's a duplicate of the question I linked to. If that in fact was not your intention, please [edit] this question to better reflect your intention and it can be reopened to answerers.

Comment: Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan, relying on the book, Sefer ha-Temunah (Book of the Figure) wrote that there were other worlds before Adam and Eve. These worlds were populated by people who were still alive when Adam and Eve were created.

Comment: It is clear that Cain and Abel are the first recorded after the fall. No other recorded names at the time Cain is being sent away. So who are the people that Cain is in fear of killing him?